# Some doubts regarding the effective potential for Kerr geometry

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, kerr-metric

In the review [Foundations of Black Hole Accretion Disk Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5499.pdf), the authors defines an effective potential for Kerr geometry as (Chap. 2, eqn. 23)
$$\Phi_{eff}=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|g^{tt}-2lg^{t\phi}+l^2g^{\phi\phi}\right|$$ where $l=\frac{\mathcal{L}}{\mathcal{E}}=-\frac{u_\phi}{u_t}$ is the specific angular momentum, $\mathcal{L}=p_\phi$ is the angular momentum and $\mathcal{E}=-p_t$ is the energy. Inserting the metric coefficients, one can find that the form of the effective potential is
$$\Phi_{eff}=1+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{r(r^2+a^2-2r)}{r^3+a^2(r+2)-4al-l^2(r-2)}\right)$$
Now I tried to observe whether this potential corresponds to the [Paczynski-Wiita potential](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1980A%26A....88...23P) for the special case of Schwarzschild geometry (i.e. $a=0$) which reads
$$\Phi_{PW}=-\frac{1}{r-2}+\frac{\tilde{l}^2}{2r^2}$$
where $\tilde{l}$ is related to $l$ as $l=\dfrac{\tilde{l}}{u_t}$.

**MY CALCULATIONS:**

I expanded the effective potential (for $a=0$) as
$$\Phi_{eff}=1+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{r(r-2)}{r^3-l^2(r-2)}\right)=1-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x)$$
where $x=2\left(\dfrac{l^2}{2r^2}-\dfrac{1}{r-2}\right)$, so that we obtain for $-1<x<1$, the following result:
$$\Phi_{eff}=1+\left(\dfrac{l^2}{2r^2}-\dfrac{1}{r-2}\right)+\left(\dfrac{l^2}{2r^2}-\dfrac{1}{r-2}\right)^2+\dots$$
**Here I observe the following unusual things:**

1. The first term of the above expansion exactly corresponds to that of the Paczynski-Wiita form, *but with $\tilde{l}$ replaced by $l$*. I couldn't understand the significance of this similarity.
2. When I plotted the curves for the effective potential, I found that the effective potential curves (for a value of $l$) almost matches with that of the exact potential curves of Kerr geometry (for the corresponding value $\tilde{l}$), except that for the marginally bound orbit, $\tilde{l}$ becomes exactly equal to $l$. I couldn't understand what is going wrong for (only) the marginally bound orbit.